# Can I specify primary key when linking Oracle view from MS Access?

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc

I need to create a linked table from MS Access to a view in Oracle.  I am creating the linked table from VBA using the following

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", [ODBC connect stuff], _
                       acTable, mySourceView, myDestinatonTable, , True
```

This is working and creates a link to the Oracle view.  However, Access can't decide what the primary key is when linking and so it prompts the user, which I don't want it to do.  Is there any way I can specify the primary key, or tell Access not to set a primary key, so that the primary key prompt doesn't appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the linked table manually with the primary key specified.  Go to the Immediate window by Ctrl+G and view the Connect string using the following:
?CurrentDb.TableDefs("tablename").Connect

Then, using the code as [ACC2000: Procedure to Create Data Sources and Relink ODBC Tables](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208295/en-us) as a guide you can recreate the connect string.

Comment: That did the trick -- no primary key prompt and no primary key.  Thanks!